# Issues with Triggers on Google Script

Tags: javascript, events, google-apps-script, triggers

I have the following function which works perfectly fine when I run it manually.

```
function LastUpdate() {
  var thisSS  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = thisSS.getSheetByName('Roster');
  var data = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var Edit = 0;
  var time = TimeStamp();
  var Row;
  Row = findInColumn("L", data);
  Edit = checkEdits(Row);
  if (Edit == 1)
  {
    sheet.getRange(Row,20).setValue(time);
  }
}
```

I set up a trigger manually by going to **Resources -> Triggers** and selected the above Function to execute **onEdit**. Basically, whenever a cell in the sheet is edited, I want to automatically trigger this function to execute. I am not sure what the issue is !

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT - I tried to do this and this also does not work

```
function onEdit(e)
{
LastUpdate ()
}
```

Comment: This isn't a [mcve], as it relies on `TimeStamp()`, `findInColumn()` and `checkEdits()`, none of which you've provided. Trim down your code to the smallest example needed to demonstrate the problem, then [edit] the question with that, and explain how you are invoking the trigger. With that, it should be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hi @Mogsdad Sorry about that, but you were right. The issue is with the  var data = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); line.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the simple onEdit trigger instead of the installed trigger? Since you're looking for the latest edit made by the active user that might be a much easier, faster and more stable solution.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range; //edited range

  range.getColumn();
  range.setValue(); 
  //etc

}
```

Comment: Can I call the function I wrote from the onedit function ?

Comment: A simple trigger will not be authorized to call `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();`.

Comment: Hi @Mogsdad, yes you are right ! I tried to display the active user data and it is blank. When I execute the code manually, it seems to populate correctly though. How can I fix this ?

Comment: The user is authorised after this user runs the script manually and agrees with the Auth scopes. The session (and email) of this user should be available now, even when you use the simple trigger. I don't know if there is a simple workaround to authorise the user without that user running the function manually first. If you want more control over the authorisation of users and getting data from their profiles you could write an authorization script. Read more here: https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2